# How to split scanner input into (Number) (String With Spaces) (Number)

Tags: java, arrays, split, java.util.scanner

Put very simply, the program I'm currently working on requires me to split my scanner input (For example: 2 Ham and Cheese 5.5). It's supposed to read in a grocery order and split it into three arrays   . I'm supposed to use string.split and be able to split this input into three pieces, regardless of spaces in my middle string.

**Example Input #1**: 2 Apples 0.9

**Example Output #1**:

2

Apples

0.9

**Example Input #2**: 2 More Apples 0.9

**Example Output #2**:

2

More Apples

0.9

How do I achieve that? Whenever I use string.split to split wherever there is a space, it splits "more" and "apples" when I only need it to split between a number and a string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (self explanatory):

```
String str = "2 More Apples 0.9";
int fistSpaceIndex = str.indexOf(" ");
int lastSpaceIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, fistSpaceIndex));
String name = str.substring(fistSpaceIndex, lastSpaceIndex);
Double cost = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(lastSpaceIndex));
System.out.println(quantity + " " + name + " " + cost);
```

split string by space, so everything before first space is quantity, everything after last space is cost, while remianing whatever is between is the name.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `.split("[^0-9]+")`, but that will throw away the information in between the numbers.

I guess you should switch to using a `Matcher`, derived from a `Pattern` like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9.]+)([^0-9]+)([0-9.]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("30 apples and pears 0.29");
if (m.matches()) {
   String number = m.group(1);
   String product = m.group(2);
   String price = m.group(3);
   // Continue parsing numbers ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it s obvious in your example that the input will always be like this :
quanity name price
so you can use the string.split , get the first and the last numbers , and concatinate the others Strings with space T[2]-t[n-1]